SharePoint list "text-overflow" is not showing ellipse
I have a SharePoint list which I want to show as gallery. I have a title field with a large font, thus many characters are not shown on the tile. I want to add an ellipsis at the end of text using the style attribute "text-overflow". I tested so much, but whatever I try, the ellipsis is not shown.
Here is the code I use.
{
  "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v2/column-formatting.schema.json",
  "elmType": "div",
  "attributes": {
    "class": "sp-field-borderBottomRegular sp-field-borderBottomSolid sp-css-borderColor-neutralPrimary sp-field-fontSizeLarge sp-field-bold"
  },
  "txtContent": "[$Title]",
  "style": {
    "box-sizing": "border-box",
    "padding": "0 2px",
    "overflow": "hidden",
    "white-space": "nowrap",
    "text-overflow": "ellipsis"
  }
}

Thanks for any help.
